# Serialize nested json objects to csv with serde and csv crates

Tags: json, csv, rust, serialization, serde

I am trying to convert a nested JSON object to a csv file using the serde and csv crates in rust. For example, I have a struct definition like

```
struct Foo {
 bar: Bar
}

struct Bar {
 baz: String,
 qux: String
}
```

that is getting deserialized. I'd like the serialized csv header to look like

```
bar_baz, bar_qux
```

Flattening like this seems like it would be a pretty common use case, but I can't find any flags for related field attributes in the serde docs. Since this is part of a much larger JSON response being parsed, I don't really want to implement my own serializer. Is there a quick way to get this done?

If there were something like

```
#[serde(flatten(serialize(prepend_field_name = true)))]
```

that I could place on the bar field that would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with automatic headers enabled. The [serialize function in `csv::Writer`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.serialize) has some restrictions on nested data when automatic headers are enabled. If you disable that and write the header names yourself, this is one way:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Bar,
}

#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
struct Bar {
    baz: String,
    qux: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut writer = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_writer(Vec::new());
    writer.write_record(["bar_baz", "bar_qux"]).unwrap();
    writer
        .serialize(Foo {
            bar: Bar {
                baz: "baz 1".into(),
                qux: "qux 1".into(),
            },
        })
        .unwrap();
    writer
        .serialize(Foo {
            bar: Bar {
                baz: "baz 2".into(),
                qux: "qux 2".into(),
            },
        })
        .unwrap();

    println!(
        "{}",
        String::from_utf8(writer.into_inner().unwrap()).unwrap()
    );
}
```

Output:

```
bar_baz,bar_qux
baz 1,qux 1
baz 2,qux 2
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c140fd230b2833d1801c05c775d58304)